# Keep footer at bottom of page when Vue component changes

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, footer, vue-component

anyone know how to keep the footer at the bottom of a reactive component when the component view changes? I currently have set the content to 100vh for the height CSS property, which works on first load. However, when I change the state which then changes the view, the footer stays in the same place, while the component's height grows as I add more elements. So then the footer is in the middle of the page again. Here is the component template:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="navbar" data-hide-for="medium">
      <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="navbar"></button>
      <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar" id="navbar">
      <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="brand">
            <a href="url" alt="logo">NAME</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="menu" v-if="this.$cookies.get('user')">
          <li><router-link class="link align-left" to="/sentences">Home</router-link></li>
          <li @click="logout"><a>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

   <!-- WHERE I AM HAVING THE ISSUE -->
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2017</p>
    </footer>

  </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
  footer {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  footer > p {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Thanks for any ideas of how to solve this problem!

Comment: Can you post some additional information? What is in the "top-bar" class? Are you using Vue-Router?

Comment: Check [this](https://codepen.io/devatrox/pen/wztlx) codepen.
You should be able to achieve that via flexbox, and it isn't necessarily connected to the use of Vue.

Comment: Sorry I am using the Zurb Foundation framework with Vue. That's basically their header, which I am using just to style it similar to the header.

Comment: Can you post some more of the code? Preferably showing the content as well, instead of the footer by itself?

Comment: Sorry it took so long but I changed some things. Here is the content

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) that allows you to do something after you have changed the data and VueJS has updated the DOM based on your data change

```
method:{ 

    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.scrollToEnd();
    });
    
    scrollToEnd: function () {
    var messages = this.$el.querySelector(your component)
    messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this methods to keep footer in the bottom in [here](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)